# Style of subsection part

Tags: bold, elsarticle

I am new to latex; hence, this can be trivial question. However, I could not handle it.

I want to make my subsection title bold and italic. I tried some methods, but I could not accomplish it.

```
\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{My Life}
\end{document}
```

The style of subsection part `My Life` is italic and not bold. I want to make it both bold and italic. By the way, I have to use the document class in sample code above. It is necessity provided by article owners of my university.

Comment: Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165930/bold-and-italic-subsection-title-with-custom-font-size

Comment: Could you please clarify on "by article owners of my university"? If you wish to use `elsarticle` because you want to publish a paper with them, it might be better to not change their style.

Answer (score 1):

[image: subsection]

```
\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                {3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {1.5ex \@plus.2ex\noindent}%
                {\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}%
                }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{My Life}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is my comment as an answer, use package titlesec:

```latex
\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{17}\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{My Life}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]